# Swift label under another label

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

How to implement one line above another, as in the screenshot.
The translation must be strictly above the word. How to do it ?

[image]

Comment: Use two labels, one above another.

Comment: @dahiya_boy it is necessary that the letter was directly above the letter. If you use two labels, it looks not so beautiful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A label under another label, with constraints as: spacing, center, equal widths and height...

Comment: Use one label pair per word. In your example that’s a total of 10 labels. It’s either that or learn custom TextKit layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use CollectionView with flowLayout set to Horizontal, where UICollectionViewCell will hold 2 labels, one above another. Set top label's font smaller as you wish and larger for bottom label. Provide collecitonView's data source as pair of words, one for top label other for bottom label. And set collectionViewCell's UI as whole collectionView would appear as single label.

Comment: So it is necessary to use collectionview?

Comment: @dahiya_boy Necessary? No. The simplest option? Probably yes.

Comment: Yes collection View is simple and dynamic option so you can have text lines as long as you want.

Comment: @ShmeelAhmad Agreed, but what if all 5 pairs of text should be seen on screen and OP does not want to scroll for more text? How will you do this?

Comment: set collectionView's width = viewController.view.frame.size.width, and in flowLayoutDelegate method, sizeForItem return collecitonView's Width/(number of pairs) and disable uicollecitonView's scrolling. 
Also use in collecitonView Cell

label.numberOfLines = 1
label.minimumFontSize = 8
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES